# Removing element from JList is not working

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

I have a JList that lists an arrayList. When I press the button called delete I want to delete the selected element from the list (and ideally the arraylist). At the moment I have the following code, however it is not working. By this I mean that it seems to do nothing if an element is selected and it gives me a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when nothing is selected.

```
private JList listOrders = new JList(arrayList.toArray());

public void myList() {
    listOrders.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION );
    panelForLists.add(listOrders);
}

public void updateList() {
    listOrders.setListData(arrayList.toArray());
    listOrders.revalidate();
    listOrders.repaint();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == deleteItem) {
         int index = listOrders.getSelectedIndex();
            listOrders.remove(index);
           updateList();
    }
}
```

I assume that maybe it's because I have to add in a ListSelectionListener somewhere, but I don't know how I can work this. I've searched on the internet for an answer for ages and this was what I came up with from the JList oracle demo.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you have to test `if(listOrders.getSelectedIndex() > -1)` before rest of code that deleting element for JList

Comment: This is probably (almost definitely) very bad practice but I managed to come up with a solution to my problem: Instead of doing `listOrders.remove(index);` I used `arrayList.remove(index);` With the update method then refreshing the list it effectively removed the item from the list and the arraylist in the one method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically what Hovercraft Full Of Eels already answered, but with some more code pointers.

1. You indeed remove and re-add the element, which of course has no effect. The easiest would be if your `ArrayList` could be used directly as `ListModel` but this is not possible (as the `ArrayList` does not fire any events). You might be tempted to use the `JList( Vector )` constructor instead, but that one does not allow to modify the vector afterwards. So you are stuck with creating your own `ListModel`. The `DefaultListModel` class is probably just what you are looking for.
2. The code in your `actionPerformed` method always assume there is an element selected. Note that the `getSelectedIndex` method returns -1 when nothing is selected. The best thing you could do (for the user) is to disable the delete button when nothing is selected, or when more then one element is selected. This can be achieved by letting the action behind the button listen to the selection model of the list, and update its enabled state depending on the selection (do not forget to fire a `PropertyChangeEvent` if needed). If you do not work with an `Action` backing up the button, just switch the enabled state of the button directly based on the selection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's helped me understand how ArrayLists work with JLists a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be removing the item from the list and then adding it right back again when you call `updateList()` and this method calls `setListData(...)` on the JList. I think that you should get rid of that method. The ListModel should hold the data, and there's no need to call `revalidate()` or `repaint()` on the JList after changing its data.

Answer (score 2):

You need use the `ListModel` for remove the selected element.

```
int index = listOrders.getSelectedIndex();
ListModel model = listOrders.getModel();
```

`JList` use an javax.swing.AbstractListModel for build the model when you call `setListData`.

You need implement your own `ListModel` extends the `javax.swing.AbstractListModel` for put CRUD methods.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a model that properly updates it

```
class ArrayListModel<T> extends AbstractListModel{

    private final List<T> arr = new ArrayList<T>();
    public int getSize(){
        return arr.size();
    }

    public T getElementAt(int ind){
        return arr.get(ind);
    }

    public void remove(int ind){
        arr.remove();
        fireIntevalRemoved(this,ind,ind);
    }


    public void add(T obj){
        arr.add(obj);
        fireIntevalAdded(this,arr.size(),arr.size());
    }

    public void setData(List<T> list){
        int size=arr.size();
        arr.clear();
        arr.addAll(list);
        fireIntevalChanged(this,0,arr.size()>size?arr.size():size);
    }

}
```

and set the model of the list with setModel

Comment: What is the added value of this `ArrayListModel` class ? You still cannot use the `ArrayList` directly and need to make all modifications on the `ListModel`. Why not just stick to the `DefaultListModel` then. An added value would be to switch to a `Collection` which actually fires events when elements are added/removed/... and use that `Collection` instance directly to back a `ListModel`, allowing changes to be made to either the `Collection` or the `ListModel`

Comment: @Robin yeah that's an option you can take but it's easier to do it this way, and if you generally don't need the List interface for stuff like that